# Why am I always in offline mode to friends?

Tags: dota-2

I've just re-installed Dota2, and now when I log in, I always appear in offline mode to my friends. How do I configure the settings to be in online mode again?
Below is my steam setting, I didn't change anything in here, just install dota2 and play, but got problem like that. 
Any other ideas? 
[image: my steam setting]

Comment: One way to come online (not sure how permanent) is to bring up the overlay from ingame, open friends if it isn't, and there should be a "Sign In" button.

Comment: edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

You just have to be online on steam. You can set it up in the steam "Friend" window next to your picture click on the arrow and select online

You also need to check "Automatically sign into Friends when I start Steam" in the Friend's settings (see picture below) :

[image]

Comment: but I must do it everytime I login Dota2, how to config to be Online as default ?

Comment: @LongTTH there is an option in the settings menu "Friends": "Automatically sign into Friends when i start Steam" that needs to be checked